# XCode Font Size Only 14 & 18, Can't Set In Between

Tags: xcode

[image]I've looked everywhere on how to set font sizes in between the given ones in XCode.

I manually type in 16, but the XCode will not set it to 16.

Couldn't find any thread on this. Any help would be appreciated

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What sort of object gives you this dropdown? I just added a `UILabel` and can set the *system* font to anything I want. SO yeah, you probably should add two things to your question - the "control" and the specific font you are using ("regular" is the font weight).

Comment: Oh my bad I meant to specify the XCode editor font, not the actual labels or text within the app

Comment: I guess I need to ask one more question! Sorry. What version of Xcode? (So far my experience with Xcode 9 shows *many* editor changes - including "looks" (default line spacing - best as I can tell - is more).

Comment: 8.3.3, should be the most up to date stable version